# automatically add curly brackets to all if/else/for/while etc. in a java code-base

Tags: java, formatting, sonarqube

I want to reduce the number of sonar violations in a large legacy java code-base, and it seems a "quick win" would be to update all these conditional statements to have curly brackets. This seems like an easy thing to do and I can't see why it wouldn't be readily automatable.

Does anybody know of a tool that could perform a bulk operation like this? Or why to do such a thing might be a bad idea before I go and spend the time writing something myself? If I were to write one myself what would be the best tools to use? Ideally something that is java language aware, so that I don't have to deal with formatting corner-cases and the like.

The rule is non-negotiable by the way, so this really is the best approach.

Comment: how should a tool determine where to put a closing bracket?

Comment: @gefai: Thats easy. The closind bracket must be placed behind the next statement, exectly as the compiler would place it. Statemens are delimitted bei ; or linebreak. Comments have te filtered out.

Comment: Why don't you just simply shut off that Sonar rule?  Is that really the big issue in your code base?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) and click `Clean-up` on the whole project. In `Clean-up` profile configuration select `Code style` tab. There you can select `Use blocks in if/while/for/do statements` as `Always`.

Comment: so this can just run against the entire code-base as a single operation? I could set it off and go get a coffee while it's doing its thing? sounds like the right answer if so!

Comment: It depends on how big the code is and how long it takes you to drink coffee. But yes, it's a single operation for the entire code-base.

Comment: it will be a 'vente' at least

Comment: If this works reliably for you, then it seems an  easy solution, unless you are unskilled at drinking coffee.  If it does not work out, I know of truly language aware tool that can do this easily and reliably.

Comment: Update before the reformatting, and check-in before making further changes.  This will simplify backing out the change if necessary.

Comment: @ira i would also be interested in hearing of this truly language aware tool!

Comment: We have used the eclipse auto-formatting on a code base of several hundred thousand lines (some of them already correctly surrounded by braces) without any issues or resulting test failures after introducing sonar (and concluding that it is a good idea to leave the relevant rule in place).

Comment: ...And I fail to see what could be dangerous about it, conceptually. After all, if the eclipse guys can write their own java compiler, they sure can figure out which statement or line after a condition is covered by it.

Comment: It's neither dangerous nor slow. Unless you have an insanely large code base it should not take more than a few seconds. I've had this enabled for years on Eclipse as part of the on save cleanup actions and for that the overhead is not noticable. I switched recently to Intellij and the lack of a way to do this has been bugging me.

Answer (score 15):

First enable `Control flow statement without braces` in the inspection settings.

IntelliJ Idea -> Run Code Inspection -> Quick Fix (works at least in the commercial version)

In newer IntelliJ versions (e.g. 2022.02) execute menu `Code` -> `Analyze Code` -> `Run Inspection By Name` -> `Code flow statement without braces` -> `Fix All`

Comment: nice one, I'll give this a look. I can target the entire 'module' in this case?

Comment: Yes. IntelliJ has a lot of Inspections with Quick fix. You also can change viable.equals("constant") to "constant".equals(vriable), to avoid NPE automaticlly.

Comment: Yeah that constant.equals(variable) pattern is a beauty.. surprised people don't use it more often!

Comment: It is like Master Yoda would speak. And thats looks strange.

Comment: I had often thought the notion of equality in java was flawed anyway i.e. that '==' tests identity and '.equals' tests equality; in my mature years I'm thinking an 'is' operator would be better for former and '==' should call the latter

Comment: In newer versions, this is under `Analyze` -> `Run Inspection By Name` -> `Run Code Inspection`

Comment: @Tadhg Analyze -> Run Inspection By Name -> Control flow statement without braces

Answer (score 6):

While it is advisable to be cautious with legacy code, it is also a good thing to detect bugs in legacy code ... or at least make the bugs easier to spot.

Let us consider Brian Agnew's difficult cases:

```
// Case #1
if (x) doMethodA(); doMethodB();
```

In fact, as far as the JLS and the Java compiler are concerned, this *means*

```
if (x) doMethodA();
doMethodB();
```

So when the transformer rewrites the code to:

```
if (x) { 
    doMethodA();
}
doMethodB();
```

it is not changing the meaning of the code, but it is correcting a problem that is likely to cause someone to *misread* the code, and *miss* a potential bug *that is in the code already*; i.e. if the 2nd call is supposed to be conditional ...

```
// Case #2
if (x) 
    // doMethodA();
    doMethodB();
```

Once again, when that is rewritten, you should get:

```
 if (x) {
    // doMethodA();
    doMethodB();
 }
```

which means the same thing as the original.  Furthermore, this most likely reflects the intent of the programmer ... if the indentation is to be believed.  But consider this:

```
// Case #2a
if (x) 
    // doMethodA();
doMethodB();
```

When we rewrite that as

```
if (x) {
    // doMethodA();
    doMethodB();
}
```

the actual meaning of the code doesn't change, and the incorrect indentation is no longer going to mislead.  If the programmer decides to uncomment the first call, he might not realize that the previous commenting out had had an unintended consequence.  (The evidence was in the original indentation that we have "fixed".)  But there is a potential solution; see below.

---

If we assume that the code transformation tool operates with a proper understanding of the syntax and semantics of Java, then it will no break anything that wasn't already broken, and it will (to a degree) make any existing brokenness more obvious to someone reading the code.  To me, that is a zero-risk win, even for legacy code.

Now if we make the transformer smarter, it could *detect* some of the cases where the original indentation indicates a possible bug (like cases #1 and #2a above) and flag them for closer code inspection.

Comment: I specially like this samples because it shows the problem of 'working with the code' rather then 'looking at'.

Answer (score 3):

This strikes me as potentially quite dangerous. Do you have comprehensive unit test coverage ?

I can see some immediately difficult cases e.g.

```
if (x) doMethodA(); doMethodB();
```

and

```
if (x) 
  // doMethodA();
  doMethodB();
```

are two that spring to mind and can't be *naively* handled (you should be language-aware to tackle these). I wouldn't try and automate such a task unless you have language-aware and reliable tool, but rather enforce a policy that you amend code when you're changing it for other reasons, and can at that stage assert code coverage through unit tests prior to changing the code.

Comment: hi, yeah I'd specifically prefer some kind of language aware tool for just such a reason. We do have unit-tests etc. and we'd probably go through some kind of a team review process to confirm the changes are okay…

Comment: @robert it isn't a matter of language aware tools it is a matter of people writing compiler correct code, but not policy correct code

Answer (score 2):

Robert in a comment said: "@ira i would also be interested in hearing of this truly language aware tool!"

Sorry for the tease.  For the cause of the tease, check my bio.

Untease: see http://www.semanticdesigns/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html as the foundation engine, and http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html.  The pair make a fully language aware source-to-source program program transformation system.

One would accomplish this task with DMS with two source-to-source transformation rules:

```
  rule curlies_for_then_statement:(c:expression, s: statement}: 
             statement->statement
       " if (\c) \s " -> "if (\c) { \s } ";


  rule curlies_for_else_statement:(c:expression, b: block, s: statement}:
              statement->statement
       " if (\c) \b else \s " -> "if (\c) \b else { \s } ";
```

This works reliably because DMS is driven completely from a formal grammar (for Java in this case), and is not operating on raw text, but rather abstract syntax trees; this also makes in independent of layout. (It is probably useful to understand the rules that "block", "expression" and "statement" are grammar nonterminals.

Comment: okay, understood. Seems like a nice tool, and I'm surprised that there aren't more language aware tools available. I googled a lot for this kind of thing, but nothing surfaced (might want to do a bit of SEO). Anyway, as well as the other suggestions above I'll give this a look, thanks!

Comment: Can't remember exactly .. "java search & replace" .. "java regular expressions" etc. as you'd expect it returned info on doing these things with java .. fairly crowded namespace!

Comment: Those phrases are pretty vague and are really focused on other than java code changes.   Java prettying?  Reformating? Refactoring?  Yes, its hard to get the SEO right.

Answer (score 2):

Intellij 2017 support this with **Reformat Code**, if you set the right coding style in the editor settings first.

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces
```

[image: Editor settings Intellij]

Answer (score 1):

While it may be a quick sonar win, you are doing some dangerous stuff.  The recommended approach is to only fix legacy code when that code has to be revisited.  These blanket approaches are going to potentially cause very subtle bugs.  Because policy has changed your management team needs to understand that this is a massive undertaking, and should guarantee that all future code is developed to the standard.

Comment: A truly language aware tool would make this undangerous.

Answer (score 0):

> The rule is non-negotiable by the way, so this really is the best approach.

Interesting.

You have a legacy codebase that is full of style errors, AND it is not negotiable that the style errors must be fixed.

The value proposition of this exercise is (to say the least) dubious. "Legacy codebase" is often a polite way of say that the code ought to be thrown away and rewritten ... but you can't afford it.  However, apparently, you can afford to spend correcting missing braces, which is unlikely to make any real difference to maintainability.

As previous answers point out.  If you automate this style correction properly:

- It won't actually fix any bugs but it won't introduce any new ones either.
- It might remove "clues" (e.g. dubious indentation) that are would be flags for existing bugs.

But if you do the style corrections manually:

- There is a chance that you will notice some bugs.  These can be added to your issue tracker for further diagnosis and fixing.
- There is also a chance that you will introduce new bugs.  And if we assume that the existing unit / systems are non-existent or of low quality (this is a legacy codebase) then these new bugs have a fair chance of going undetected.

Now generalize across style-related errors that Sonar detects.

In summary, this whole process of fixing all of the style errors in a *legacy codebase* is (IMO) largely a waste of time if automated, and possibly risky if manual.

This *should* be negotiable.  You should be able to tell management of these concerns ...

Comment: This seems more like an extended comment than an actual attempt to answer the question. I do agree that this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though.

Comment: It is an attempt to explain why he probably shouldn't do this. And therefore why all other answers that directly answer the question are questionable. To me, this an answer to the question, albeit not a literal answer.