# How to fix repeated pmd violations programatically?

Tags: java, python, automation, pmd

I have enabled [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) for my Java project and it throws about 500 violations for the rule that "if" should have braces even it is single line. Apart from going manually and editing in all those 500 places is it possible to write a script (python, shell, ruby, etc.) which does so. If yes, then how can I go about it?

Comment: Any specific reason for down voting the question? I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: [This SO answer helps perhaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336281/automatically-add-curly-brackets-to-all-if-else-for-while-etc-in-a-java-code-ba)

Comment: Well, that was indeed what I was looking for. Thanks @gtgaxiola :) Please put it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: That's not a good reason by itself to downvote a question; just suggest or vote (depending on your possibilities) that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt who says I downvoted the question?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I agree with you. I would not have had a problem with that.
gtgaxiola I think Erwin is not referring to you for that.

Comment: @gtgaxiola I don't see anyone saying that. I see you saying that a duplicate is a reason to downvote a question, and I responded to that.

Comment: @gtgaxiola I guess we are just lost in Translation of intent. I was not responding to the reason of the downvote, I was just helping out in a comment since I didn't want to regurgitate the answer as my own.

Comment: Because there are two questions: 1. Is it possible? (yes, of course). 2. How can I go about it? (much too broad)

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. I got my answer from the link posted above in the comments. As you told there are many ways, one of the way is through eclipse which suites my need.